# Laravel 8 Change database connection globally in the runtime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My requirement is pretty simple and I found a lot of solutions, but none of them is working for me.

I have two MySQL databases, one where all write operations will happen and there is a replica of this database, which is read-only. I am creating a middleware where if a request is GET, it should use read-only database otherwise main databases.

I already have tried these:

```
DB::disconnect();
Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_readonly');
DB::reconnect('mysql_readonly');


Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_readonly');
DB::purge('mysql_readonly');


DB::disconnect();
Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_readonly');
DB::connection('mysql_readonly');
```

None of the solutions is working.

- Laravel Version: 8.59.0
- PHP Version: 8.0.10

Comment: Instead of "right operations" you mean "write operations"?

Comment: Yes, typo error. @JamesZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the working solution.

```
$readOnlyConfig = config('database.connections.mysql_readonly');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql', $readOnlyConfig);
DB::purge();
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. I really wish they'd picked a different function name than `purge`, because it's a little terrifying the first couple times.